# ktor sslConnector serve/read from jar p12 pkcs12 jks keystore and mtls mutual ssl connection

Tags: kotlin, ssl, embedded-resource, ktor, mtls

I have figured out on how to start a ktor with embeddedServer Jetty and serving https/ssl/tls using my own signed Certificate (signed by my own self-signed rootCA certificate).

Now ktor sslConnector needs to have the `keyStorePath` as `File`, but I'd prefer to serve the keystore from the/a file inside the final fat jar (mainly for being able to run it inside a kubernetes cluster)

Is there a way to tell ktor to take/read a resource embedded in its jar file as keyStore?

```kotlin
    // openssl pkcs12 -export -nodes -passout pass:${keystorePW} -in "domain.cert" -inkey "domain.key" -certfile "intermediateAndRootCAchain.ca" -name "aliasName" -out "webserverKeystore.p12"
    val keystore: KeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keystoreFile, keystorePW.toCharArray())

    @Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER")
    fun doIt(args: Array<String>) {
        val server = embeddedServer(Jetty, applicationEngineEnvironment {
            module {
                configureRouting()
                configureHTTP(sslPort)
                configureSerialization()
            }

            connector {
                this.host = host // redirected to https
                this.port = port // redirected to sslPort
            }

            sslConnector(keystore,
                keyAlias = certAlias, // alias name inside keystore: keytool -v -list -keystore certs/keystore.jks
                keyStorePassword = { keystorePW.toCharArray() },
                privateKeyPassword = { keystorePW.toCharArray() } // somehow this is the same as keystorePW if using openssl pkcs12 -export from above
            ) {
                this.port = sslPort
                keyStorePath = keystoreFile
            }
        })

        server.start(wait = true)
    }
```

Is there a way to tell ktor to take/read a resource embedded in its jar file as keyStore?

(also wondering why `sslConnector` still needs the keystore as `File` if it already got the whole keystore as first parameter, but that's probably to be independant from the actual web container that's being used)

a second question: is it possible to enable ***mutual*** tls, so that the ktor server refuses a connection if the client cannot present a valid certificate? if yes, how would I configure that?

Comment: I don't know ktor, but in _Java_ you can (still) load a KeyStore from a jar resource using the pre-9 way: `x = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12"); x.load( whatever.getResourceAsStream("/blah"), pw_chararray)` (and close logic to be tidy). Also in Java `SSLSocket/SSLEngine.setNeedClientAuth(true)` or `.setSSLParameters(containing_same)` aborts if no or bad client cert, but I don't know for ktor. PS: `openssl pkcs12 -export` ignores `-nodes` -- that applies only to the opposite 'parsing' mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Netty` and `Jetty` engines, a `keystore` that you pass as a first parameter for `sslConnector` is actually used. The `keyStorePath` property is used only for the `Tomcat` engine.

Unfortunately, there is no way to configure mutual TLS authentication in Ktor but as a workaround, you can do it manually by adding a connector to the underlying Jetty server. [This article](https://imlc.me/how-to-enable-mutual-authentication-in-jetty-server) may be useful for you. Here is an incomplete example:

```
embeddedServer(
    Jetty, 
    applicationEngineEnvironment {
        module {
            // ...
        }
    }
) {
    configureServer = {
        val factory = SslConnectionFactory(
            SslContextFactory.Server().apply {
                // keyStore = ...
                // setKeyManagerPassword(...)
                // setKeyStorePassword(...)
                needClientAuth = true
            },
            HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1.asString()
        )

        val connector = ServerConnector(this, factory).apply {
            // host = ...
            // port = ...
        }

        addConnector(connector)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my final code in usage:

```kotlin
        val (theTrustStore, theKeyStore) = createTrustStoreAndKeyStore()

        val server = embeddedServer(Jetty, applicationEngineEnvironment {
            module {
                configureRouting()
                configureHTTP(theSslPort)
                configureSerialization()
            }

            connector {
                this.host = theBindHost // redirected to https
                this.port = thePort // redirected to sslPort
            }

            // // without mTLS (m = mutual)
            // sslConnector(theKeyStore,
            //     keyAlias = theHost, // alias name inside keystore: keytool -v -list -keystore certs/keystore.jks
            //     keyStorePassword = { keystorePW.toCharArray() },
            //     privateKeyPassword = { privateKeyPW.toCharArray() } // somehow this is the same as keystorePW if using openssl pkcs12 -export from above
            // ) {
            //     this.host = theBindHost
            //     this.port = theSslPort
            //     keyStorePath = null // only used by tomcat engine
            // }
        }) {
            configureServer = {
                val factory = SslConnectionFactory(
                    SslContextFactory.Server().apply {
                        keyStore = theKeyStore
                        trustStore = theTrustStore
                        // setKeyManagerPassword(...)
                        // setKeyStorePassword(...)
                        needClientAuth = true
                    },
                    HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1.asString()
                )

                val httpConfig = HttpConfiguration()
                httpConfig.secureScheme = "https"
                httpConfig.securePort = theSslPort
                // SSL HTTP Configuration
                val httpsConfig = HttpConfiguration(httpConfig)
                httpsConfig.addCustomizer(SecureRequestCustomizer()) // so that servlets can see the encryption details


                val connector = ServerConnector(
                    this,
                    factory,
                    HttpConnectionFactory(httpsConfig)
                ).apply {
                    host = theBindHost
                    port = theSslPort
                }

                addConnector(connector)
            }
        }

        server.start(wait = true)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this example, could you share how did you implemented createTrustStoreAndKeyStore() ?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/HoffiMuc/bb183db2e9d54cf1d94a71a3705117f4